# how can unique constraint modified in postgresql for column 'A' not unique over same value in column B and unique over different values for column B?

Tags: postgresql, unique-constraint

**PROBLEM**: In a table; column 1 is not unique for same value of column 2 but column 1 value is unique over different values of column 2. How can this condition be implemented in postgreSQL db.

## Explaination

Assume table 1 exists in DB

#### Table 1

| Column A | Column B | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | apple | green |
| One | apple | blue |
| Two | apple | pink |
| Three | orange | purple |

for Column B as "apple" if  in Column A value "One" exists, then for any other value of Column B, Column A will not have "One". 
Example: element from Table 2 **Should NOT** Exist

#### Table2

| Column A | Column B | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | orange | red |

**the Extra column can have any value

Comment: if you want to forbid/exclude values that exist in **an other table**: that can only be done via a trigger.

Comment: This is a bad design & is the sort of design that DB normalization to higher NFs gets rid of.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem by properly normalizing your data model:

```
CREATE TABLE part_2 (
   column_a text PRIMARY KEY,
   column_b text NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE part_2 (
   column_a text REFERENCES part_2,
   extra text NOT NULL
);
```

(`part2` is still missing a primary key.)

Then your table would be split up like this:

`part_1`:

| column_a | column_b |
| --- | --- |
| One | apple |
| Two | apple |
| Three | orange |

`part_2`:

| column_a | extra |
| --- | --- |
| One | green |
| One | blue |
| Two | pink |
| Three | purple |

Now it is technically impossible to add data where `column_a` is identical but `column_b` is different, and your problem is solved.

If you want to retain your original table format, use a view:

```
CREATE VIEW total AS
SELECT column_a, part_1.column_b, part_2.extra
FROM part_1 JOIN part_2 USING (column_a);
```